# Flutter web: How can I close my app through code?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How can I close my Flutter web app through code?

I tried:

- exit(0)
- SystemNavigator.pop()

and non of these things worked for flutter web.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1> `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');`

2> `window.close();` by importing `dart:html` but it works only on web

Comment: Getting 'Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.' in flutter web. Used window.close().

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
`window.close()` is not working on my web app, is not throwing any error it simply not closing the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same difficulty, I managed to solve it like this, I installed the [universal_html package](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html)  and used html.window.location.reload();